# On react native when I put an if statment in the render section checking the value of a variable I get an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-native

I am trying to load the font by having so that when you press a button, your font will load. When I put the if statement in the render section, I get an error saying that:
RawText "if (fontLoaded=="true")" must be wrapped in an explicit text component. Please help me solve this, I am very confused.

I am very new to react native so this may be a very basic question, I am sorry.

My code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { Font } from 'expo';

var fontLoaded = false;

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        'Cabin-Regular-TTF': require('./Cabin-Regular-TTF.ttf'),
      });


  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { postInput: ""}
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{width: 1, height: 30, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
    <Button
    onPress={this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
    title="Press Me To Load the App After 15 Seconds!"
    color="#841584"
    accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"
    />

    if (fontLoaded=="true") {
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 16 }}>
                Whats on your mind? Create a post!
            </Text>     

        <TextInput>
            tyle={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
            onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}
                value={this.state.postInput}    
        </TextInput>

        <ScrollView>
            <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
                <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
            <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
            <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
            <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
            <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
            <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
            <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
            <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
            <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
            <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
            <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
            <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
            </ScrollView>
    </View>
                }











      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to use raw javascript inside your html. You can't use the regular `if` statement inside the `render()` function but you can use the inline conditional statement like this:

```
{isTrue ? (<div>True</div>) : (<div>False</div>)}
```

Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

In your case it'll be something like this:

```
render() {
 return (
   {/*your code as usual*/}
{fontLoaded ? (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {/*your code as usual*/}
  </View>) : 
  null}
```

Comment: Now I don't get any errors, but expo stops loading at %100 and then crashes after around 45 seconds. I tried it on my iPad and a android phone. Each time it says finished loading java script bundle in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` to achieve the same result. You have to use JSX condition inside the render method. You can write your if condition like below.

```
{fontLoaded &&
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 16 }}>
            Whats on your mind? Create a post!
        </Text>     

        <TextInput>
             style={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
             onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}
             value={this.state.postInput}    
        </TextInput>

        <ScrollView>
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
            <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
        </ScrollView>
   </View>
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and now instead of getting an error, expo stops loading at %100 and after about 45 seconds crashes. The app never loads.

Comment: Each time I try it says finished building java script bundle. I tried it on my android phone and my iPad. It didn't work either time.

Comment: It may be because of other codes, not related to this one.